# Is there a Vampire: The Masquerade character builder?

Tags: character-creation, world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, tools

I've been considering DMing some Masquerade. In my DnD group, we're big fans of the dnd4 builder. I'm wondering if there's such a tool going around and/or online. At this particular point, I'm not looking for a particular edition.

I saw that an "online toolset" coming in early 2023 is [advertised](https://app.demiplane.com/nexus/vampire) on World of Darkness Nexus, but it seems to imply more of a library function than a builder.

Comment: not only is this a shopping question, it also is undefined in edition.

Comment: ... I read how to post, I did not see anything about "shopping"? This felt like a "question"? 
Is it bad that it's undefined in edition? It leaves it more open ended??

Comment: 5th edition vampire is nothing like 1st, 2nd, revised, which are internally compatible, and 20th anniversary is somewhat different but compatible to older but not V5.